How do I handle the unmarshalled whitespace in this Go test?
I have a test for a parseFruitXML function which returns the unmarshalled struct as 'got' and uses !reflect.DeepEqual to compare this against a populated struct called 'want'.
The test reads a fruit.xml file as input to the function.
When fruit.xml is unmarshalled, this rule comes into play on the Cherries field,

"If the XML element contains character data, that data is accumulated
in the first struct field that has tag ",chardata". The struct field
may have type []byte or string. If there is no such field, the
character data is discarded."

(https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal)
How do I handle the whitespace coming from the sample xml files in the 'got' for these tests? Do I add a Cherries field in the 'want' struct with the same amount of whitespace, or use strings.TrimSpace() on the Text field of 'got', or some other approach?
Example code:
fruit.xml
<fruit>
    <apples>10</apples>
    <oranges>20</oranges>
</fruit>

fruit_test.go
package fruit_test

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "io"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type Fruits struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"fruit"`
    Cherries string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Apples   int      `xml:"apples"`
    Oranges  int      `xml:"oranges"`
}

func parseFruitXML(fruitResponse []byte) (Fruits, error) {
    f := Fruits{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(fruitResponse, &f); err != nil {
        return Fruits{}, err
    }
    return f, nil
}

func TestFruit(t *testing.T) {
    fruits, err := os.Open("fruit.xml")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("error opening fruit xml: %v", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        _ = fruits.Close()
    }()

    b, err := io.ReadAll(fruits)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    want := Fruits{
        XMLName: xml.Name{
            Local: "fruit",
        },
        Apples:  10,
        Oranges: 20,
    }
    got, _ := parseFruitXML(b)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) {
        t.Errorf("got %+v\n, want %+v", got, want)
    }
}


I'm unsure if I understand your question, but: Just stop using reflect.DeepEqual. Writing 3 ifs that check what you are interested in is much simpler than fiddling with the stuff you do not care, just to make DeepEqual work.

If you don't want the chardata, don't capture it.  If you want to capture it, add it to your expected data.

@Volker thanks. As the test is interested in comparing the entire struct not specific Fields, and my real struct is much more complex (with e.g. slices of structs that have nested structs) my understanding was that I needed to use DeepEqual to compare them? Though I also found reference to this package in other answers - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp.

@erik258 thanks, this takes a step back and feels like the right approach to me. I'm not interested in the chardata, so I no longer capture it
